# how to import customer with full billing & shipping address programatically?

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

how to import customer with full billing & shipping address programatically from csv?

I want to run php script from commandline.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a script that:

- loads the Magento app once.
- iterates through each line of .csv as single record, or loads all records into an array which then can be iterated.
- validates all data elements against Magento's data validation rules for customer records.
- checks for the existence of a customer record with the import record's email address.
- either skips record on email match or updates record (whatever you choose).
- creates a customer record where there is no match.
- validates the billing address in import record against Magento's data validation rules for addresses.
- creates an address of type billing populated from that record, and marks it default (if you want it so marked).
- validates the shipping address in import record against Magento's data validation rules for addresses.
- creates an address of type shipping populated from that record, and marks it default (if you want it so marked).

That will result in what you have suggested. You might find scripts out there that are already close to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The skeleton of your script would look as follows:

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::app()->getStore());

if ($_FILES['csv']['error'] == 0) {
    // import csv to array
}

foreach ($customers as $customer) {
    $email = /* email */;
    $newCustomer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer');
    $newCustomer->setWebsiteId( Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId() );
    $newCustomer->setStore( Mage::app()->getStore() );
    $newCustomer->loadByEmail( $email );
    $exists = $newcustomer->getId();
    if(!$exists){
        $newCustomer->setEmail( $email );
        $newCustomer->setFirstname( /* first name */ );
        $newCustomer->setMiddlename( /* middle name */ );
        $newCustomer->setLastname( /* last name */ );

        // this creates a new password
        // importing a passwords is a whole other thing
        $newPassword = $newCustomer->generatePassword();
        $newCustomer->setPassword( $newPassword );
        $createdDate= new Zend_Date( /* date created */ );
        $newCustomer->setCreatedAt($createdDate->toString('Y-M-d H:m:s'));

        // save new customer
        try {
            $newCustomer->setConfirmation(null);
            $newCustomer->save();
        }

        catch (Exception $ex) {
            Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
        }

        // create address to save

        $newAddress=array(
            'firstname'     => /* address first name */,
            'lastname'      => /* address last name */,
            'street'            => array(
                    '0' => /* address street line 1 */,
                    '1' => /* address street line 2 */,
            ),
            'city'          => /* address city */,
            'region_id'     => /* address region id */,
            'region'        => /* address region */,
            'postcode'      => /* address postcode */,
            'country_id'    => /* address country id */,
            'telephone'     => /* address telephone */,
        );

        // save address

        $address=Mage::getModel('customer/address');
        $address->setData($newAddress)
            ->setCustomerId($newCustomer->getId())
            ->setIsDefaultBilling('1')
            ->setIsDefaultShipping('1')
            ->setSaveInAddressBook('1');
        try {
            $address->save();
        }

        catch (Exception $ex) {
            Zend_Debug::dump($ex->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```